# z-index issue with relative and absolute positioning combination

Tags: css, positioning, z-index

Please look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/R39qL/) and show me how to make the blue `<div>` go behind the pink `<div>`. As you can see I have all ready tried this with the CSS z-index attribute, but without success.

---

### [Update]

[New Link](http://jsfiddle.net/R39qL/5/) Now my buttons in the blue div don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/R39qL/1/).

Pink `div` has opacity so you can see the results.

The blue `div` can't be a child of the pink `div`.

Comment: i don't think he was looking for opacity magicks for his problem though

Comment: @corroded The opacity is only to show in this example the pink `div` is above the `blue` one.

Comment: Thank you your example works but when I put buttons in the blue `<div>` it doesn't work.

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer It won't work because it is behind the other `div`.

Comment: For what I am doing then the blue div has to be a child of the main div. Is there a way I could make this work?

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer I'm not sure sorry. Best of luck.

Comment: @alex ah sorry for that misunderstood what you said

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in **[mozilla developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context)**, "stacking context is completely independent from its siblings: only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed".

I suppose you cannot do it using zIndex but, you can make it invisible by using opacity.